# Continuous Backup of Mediawiki

Tags: mysql, backup, mediawiki

I am administrating mediawiki for my organisation. We use it as our Intranet site. It has accumulated a huge organisational knowledge base. I have make sure that mediawiki is always up and running. Knowledge base always backed up.

Is there a way to take continuous back of mediawiki files and databases? My mediawiki is hosted on LAMPP server with Debian OS.

I am trying to find a way to automate backup process.

Comment: Off-topid for SO; belongs on [sf] or possibly [su]

Comment: I would recommend MySQL database replication (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). This is a feature that MySQL supports which will copy your data to another database, which could be on a different machine. This doesn't cover files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "continuous". If you want a copy of the database running that is always the same as the main database, you will need to set up "replication" - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html for how to do that.

If you want a database backup that is relatively current, then running mysqldump every hour or so is a pretty good solution.

You'll need to backup the files separately, because they are in your file system not the database. Look at running `rsync` every hour or so.

Why do you want a "continuous" backup and how would you use it? Do either of these approaches answer your question?

Comment: It partially answer my question.Update my question with more details. Hope this helps.